# Revert Changes to Kusto Query in MSAI

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I recently found out someone accidentally overwrote one of my Kusto queries in Azure Application Insights. Is there a way to revert a query to a previously saved version of it? Or do I really have no other choice but to rewrite the query?

The query is a Legacy Query in the Other Category under Queries in the Azure Logs. I cannot show much more, since this is work related.

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify where a query was overwritten (Alert, Saved Query, Query powering dashboard tile, etc.)? Screenshot would be the best.

Comment: @ZakiMa , I updated the post above with a screenshot but cannot share much, since this is work-related. It is a Legacy Query in the Other Category under Queries in the Azure Logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a workaround on your issue, I found that there is no default feature in Azure workspace for reverting a query to a previously saved version of it.

*Below are the few workarounds you can look into.*

1. Under `application insights >> logs` in the portal, you can be able to view the history of the queries which shows you the query ran in the past.

[image]

2. [Save the query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/save-query#save-options) before any conflict or issue happens. Because when you save a query, it will gets automatically stored in a query pack which will not get deleted until you delete it. Refer
3. Alternatively, you can use restore data management to retrieve the activities done in the past with the help of an API or a CLI command `az monitor log-analytics workspace table restore`.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/restore?tabs=cli-1) for more relevant information.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will try them out when I start to work again next week. I was not aware if the queries history. It seems like exactly what I am looking for.